# Gmail iOS app like dropdown menu

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, menu, gmail

i would like to know if there are any frameworks for iOS to make a dropdown menu like the Gmail App
[image: When whe tap the arrow]
[image: We get this menu with a little animation]

Thanks !

Comment: Any links to those frameworks ?

Comment: If you're asking if there is any preconfigured framework to make a menu like this then no. However, the UIKit framework does exist, in which you can create your own custom controls like the one in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah sure, as much s you can recreate every single UI element on the web. My question is if there are any base framework to those kind of menus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of any frameworks, but this would be a pretty small amount of code to get working. All you need is a view with a background colour with alpha < 1, and put some buttons on it. Then slide it in and out using UIView animations. Hey presto.

You can create the view in interface builder to save yourself some time, and put if off the top of the view. To animate it in, just use something like:

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    CGRect menuFrame = self.menuView.frame;
    if (menuFrame.origin.y >= 0) {
        // menu is visible
        menuFrame.origin.y = -menuFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        // menu is invisible, slide it on screen
        menuFrame.origin.y = 0;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
        self.menuView.frame = menuFrame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm ! Just a note to those who would want to reuse this code, you should change the `if (menuFrame.origin.y > 0)` into `if (menuFrame.origin.y >= 0)`

Comment: @senly oops, edited for correctness